1960's American comedy about oil workers in fictional Middle-Eastern country
I remember having seen this movie several times, (so I know it exists), but haven't heard anything about it in a long time.
Technical
The movie is definitely American, in English, color, from the 1960's.  The tone is like a slapstick comedy, with 1960's tame adult humor.
Plot
It was about some oil workers who were contracted to work in a tiny, fictional Middle-Eastern Sultanate.  I think they arrived by cargo plane.  The Sultan is a jolly man who loves to play with miniature toy trains and other toys.
One of the contractors falls in love and romances, (in the usual 1960's sexist way), the Sultan's daughter, and gets into a lot of trouble with the Sultan.
I remember one lengthy scene where the contractors decide to teach the people there American Football, but without any grass, someone paints a football-sized area of sand green.
That's about all I can remember.  (I asked about this movie on imdb.com but didn't get any responses there a few years ago).

Sounds like you're looking for the farcical comedy John Goldfarb, Please Come Home! from 1965 with Richard Crenna and Shirley MacLaine.

[The] tale concerns John "Wrong-Way" Goldfarb, a former college football star who once ran 95 yards for a touchdown in the wrong direction. Now a U-2 pilot, his plane malfunctions and crashes in the mythical Arab kingdom of Fawzia. The country's leader threatens to turn him over to the Soviets unless he agrees to coach a football team.

Peter Ustinov plays the oil sheik who's obsessed with toy trains. The film is currently on Youtube. Here's a clip from it:



